# vipJ unwrapping fails when using custom function

Tags: word-processing

I have decided to use Vim for editing prose, as I find it to be a much more work-conducive, clutter-free environment than most so-called text processors expressly built for that purpose. To that end, and on the advice of some internet stranger with a blog, I added this function to my vimrc to quickly enable (and disable, I suppose? I don't really know how to tell whether the function has been turned off again) a prose-editing mode which sets a text width and text-wrapping options that make sense for natural languages:

```
func! WordProcessorMode()
    setlocal formatoptions=ant
    setlocal textwidth=72
    setlocal wrapmargin=0
endfu

com! WP call WordProcessorMode()
```

However - as has already been adressed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039544/unwrap-text-in-vim - sometimes I would like to unwrap that text in order to paste it into a forum post (as I'm doing right now) or an e-mail editor, or whatever. When I try to `vipJ` under this custom word-wrapping mode, though, nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: I think the reason is the `a` flag in `formatoptions`, which tells Vim to automatically reformat a paragraph after text is inserted or deleted. Apparently, Vim sees that `vipJ` as having inserted and/or deleted text, so it reformats the paragraph, restoring the original line breaks. One way to fix the problem is to execute `:setlocal fo-=a` before executing `vipJ`.

Comment: Thanks for that, @garyjohn.

I wound up adding the following function to my vimrc to help prepare text for pasting into a web form or word processor:
func! PastePrepare()
> setlocal fo-=a
> execute "normal vipJ"
> endfu
> com! PP call PastePrepare()